# Auto send confirmation when loading package (creditr)

Tags: r

I am trying to automate a routine using functions from `creditr` package and integrating it with excel. The problem is  that every time I load the package using `library()` or `require()` it is necessary to agree with terms by imputing "yes".

Is there a way to automatically answer "yes" or force the package to load?

Comment: Technically speaking (without considering how this could infringe the license terms), you could fork or download the project from its GitHub page and modify the source file containing the .onAttach function, and then rebuild it locally.

Comment: ... as long as, if you distribute it anywhere, you [preserve its `LICENSE`](https://github.com/davidkane9/creditr/blob/master/LICENSE).

Comment: They require user input? I can't find `readline` in [the source](https://github.com/davidkane9/creditr), how is it requiring user input?

Comment: When you first load the package in a section, a massage with the package and license descrpition is printed, asking for agreement to the terms:

Comment: "IF YOU USE THIS CDS PACKAGE, YOUR USE WILL SIGNIFY YOUR....    Please type **yes** to assent to the aforementioned terms."                                                                                         
       Unless you send "yes", the script won't continue to run. I've figure out a way to overcome this problem by running r from windows command prompt, but the idea of changing the source code locally sounds great.